# Angular: 'modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, model-view-controller

I'm trying to learn Angular and hitting a brick wall trying to add routes to my application.

I keep getting presented this error

> 'modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module

From other stackoverflow questions i gather its not from loading ngRoute correctly but angular-route.js is loaded in the head, and ngRoute is declared in my module construct so i'm a bit confused

My index file is as followed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/animations.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="pgpChatApp">
  <div class="view-container">
    <div ng-view="" class="view-frame"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My app file

```
'use strict';

var pgpChatApp = angular.module('pgpChatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'firebase',
  'pgpChatAnimations',
  'pgpChatControllers',
  'pgpChatFilters',
  'pgpChatServices'
]);

pgpChatApp.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/home", {
    // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
    controller: "userAuth",
    templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
  }).when("/account", {
    // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
    controller: "AccountCtrl",
    templateUrl: "partials/msg_room.html",
    resolve: {
      // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
      // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function (Auth) {
        // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
        // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
        return Auth.$requireAuth();
      }]
    }
  });
}]);
```

My controller file

```
var pgpChatAppControllers = angular.module('pgpChatAppControllers', []);

pgpChatAppControllers.controller("userAuth", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "Auth",
  function ($scope, $routeParams, Auth) {
    $scope.createUser = function () {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      Auth.$createUser({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      }).then(function (userData) {
        $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + userData.uid;
      }).catch(function (error) {
        $scope.error = error;
      });
    };

    $scope.removeUser = function () {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      Auth.$removeUser({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      }).then(function () {
        $scope.message = "User removed";
      }).catch(function (error) {
        $scope.error = error;
      });
    };
  }]);
```

Has anyone got an idea what the fix is?

Thanks in advanced

[EDIT]
Full exception message

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=pgpChatAnimations&p1=Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=pgpChatAnimations
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:21:412
>       at a (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:21:53)
>       at w.bootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:21:296)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:35:116
>       at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:7:302)
>       at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:34:399)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:35:63
>       at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:7:302)"

Comment: Where in your code is "modulerr" referenced? *note the double r's.

Comment: Loading angular after angularfire results in an additional error, angularfire is a firebase plugin for angular.

@AndrewF i've included the full exception message above

Comment: In the first file you have `var pgpChatApp = angular.module('pgpChatApp', ...)`, then in the second: `var pgpChatAppControllers = angular.module('pgpChatAppControllers', [])` -- you probably don't want the second module, and should just add the controller to `pgpChatApp`.

Comment: Okay then you should load js files as it is but without the protocols. Like `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"`. Make sure for all of them

Comment: @JamesKirkby create a fiddle ..

Comment: Its not the loading of any external resources all my resources are loading absolutly fine

@pdenes i've copied out the structure of the app from https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat

var pgpChatAppControllers is defined in the app.js file when it loads in ngRoutes and firebase

Comment: If you follow the link from the error message, it shows that "Module 'pgpChatAnimations' is not available". So maybe that file is simply missing...?

Comment: I didn't see any error in your code. Probably its something depending upon sequence you're loading your files. Please load `app.js` on the last of all js. I mean after `\service.js`

Comment: i've added my project to github so you can see the structure which is better than a fiddle

https://github.com/jkirkby91/angular-firebase-chat

Comment: have you tried what I've commented

Comment: im loading the files in the correct order see the angular demo

https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/index.html

Comment: filters.js and animations.js seem empty... :)

Comment: Also, in index.html, you're only including app.js controllers.js, and services.js, but trying to reference modules defined / to be defined in other files.

Answer (score 0):

The url for angular-route is not working. Try using:

```
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-route.js
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was using a different version of angular js. I removed the references to animations, filters and services since you didnt provide those sources and the app works just fine... which makes me think the error is in one of those files.

Comment: Also, you should include your app.js as the last file since it may not be waiting for the others to load before running... meaning it may not find the definition to your other modules.

Comment: the correct method loads app.js first as you are defining pgpChatApp that is used later on see this angular demo

https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess i my module names still weren't matching the defined modules in app.js

This diff shows the fix

https://github.com/jkirkby91/angular-firebase-chat/commit/35be74592197d16435adb322f0e24963108ed97a